# Deep Copy of a struct with another struct pointer

Tags: c, memcpy

I am trying to copy the contents of one struct to another temp struct so i can alter the RGB pixels of the temp struct without affecting the outcome (if i altered the global pixels instead).

Code
 Structs

```
//the pixel structure
typedef struct {
    GLubyte r, g, b;
} pixel;

//the global structure
typedef struct {
    pixel *data;
    int w, h;
} glob;
glob global, original, temp;
```

my copy Code

```
void copyPic(glob *source, glob *dest){
    int x,y;
    dest -> w = source -> w;
    dest -> h = source -> h;
    dest -> data = (pixel *) malloc(dest->w * dest->h * sizeof(pixel*));
    for (x=0; x < dest -> w; x++)
        for (y=0; y < dest -> h; y++){
            memcpy(dest->data[x+y*dest->w], source->data[x+y*dest->w], sizeof(pixel))

        }

}
```

The idea: the glob struct holds the image width, height and pixel* data which is a pointer to an array of R,G,B values.

I want to copy the global to temporary so when i change the RGB of temp->data it doesnt affect the code that is currently executing and basing changing the RGB off the RGB of global->data.

New Code

```
void copyPic(glob *src, glob *dest){

dest -> w = src -> w;
dest -> h = src -> h;
dest -> data = (pixel *) malloc(dest->w * dest->h * sizeof(pixel));

memcpy(dest->data, src->data, sizeof(pixel) * dest->w  * dest->h);
```

}

Do i have to free anything?

Comment: For your own sanity, I'm telling you now that if your `dest` ever already has an image data set bound to it, this is going to leak memory like a sieve leaks water. And *neither* loop is needed. A simple `memcpy()` will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `memcpy` many times (w * h). I would suggest that you copy only once

```
memcpy(dest->data, source->data, sizeof(pixel) * w * h);
```

Comment: I just get memory error violations when I changed dest->w and dest->h. you would replace the last 4 lines with that one line?

Comment: @George update your question and show the code that makes the call to this function, *including* the *declaration* of both the `source` and `dest` structures you're passing into this function. It sounds like you have an uninitialized source, destination, or both. You say "I want to copy the global to a temporary" Well that makes it pretty important that  `global` is properly set and doesn't contain indeterminate values.

Answer (score 0):

First: your API is not very cooperative. By assigning to dest->data, you could possibly overwrite its previous contents, and thus : *leak memory*. If you sole purpose is to duplicate the struct object (using a deep copy) it will be IMHO more robust to implement this as a *dup* operation like:

```
glob * dup_the_Pic(glob *src) {
glob * dst;

  dest = malloc (sizeof *dst);
  // maybe check for malloc failure here
  memcpy (dst,src, sizeof *dst);

  dst->data = malloc(dst->w * dst->h * sizeof *dst->data);
  // maybe check for malloc failure here, too
  memcpy(dst->data, src->data, dst->w  * dst->h * sizeof *dst->data);

return dst;
}
```

To be called like:

```
glob *the_original, *the_copy;

the_original = read_thing_from_file( ...);

the_copy = dup_the_Pic(the_original);
do_stuff_with_the_pic(the_copy);
```